# Optimization tips for WP code and high data volumes

Tags: wordpress, performance

Looking for tips on how I might re-factor a shortcode which outputs a table of custom post types with meta field values that is hitting memory limits with 250 - 300 results on page.

**Setup Details**
Using Gravity Forms Quiz add-on and WCK Custom Field / Post Type Creator I have setup a training system which has the following custom post types for different data collections (capitals) and general flow. STUDENT is scheduled in CLASSES that can have multiple COURSES that are collection of QUIZZES. Each time a student takes a quiz they generate a result which has separate meta data fields identifying the ID of the course, class, quiz and student.

The current version uses [datatables jQuery](http://www.datatables.net) to display all the results to the class teacher and handle pagination, search, sort, download to .xls and other table features. But I'm hitting some memory / performance issues with the number of results to loop through WP_Query is over 250.

The analysis page uses a shortcode - [code snippet pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zJNR1XD8) to output the table data, essentially:

- WP_Query Loops through each COURSE, CLASS and QUIZ custom post type storing ID / Title in it's own array with ID as key.
- foreach loop through all users and stores as an array for name, email
- WP_Query loop through all RESULTS and does a match based on meta data for right data to present.

Looking for tips on how I might re-factor this or which would be best to focus on first with the only real caveat being that keeping GF Quiz as data entry point. Some things I've been considering:

1. Optomizing the WP_Query params
2. Are CPT and meta fields the right place to store this?
3. Is something in how WCK generates it's CPTs adding to massive overhead?
4. Using WP Ajax pagination for results and a separate build process to download .csv. But how would that download be built without hitting same performance problems?
5. Does the WP import / export code offer some examples I really should look at?
6. Other examples where people have 1,000's of results to display to page / download?
7. I doubt "throw more hardware at it" is viable solution as environment generally is pretty responsive for load. But if so, what area should focus on given the scenario (multi-core, processor speeds, memory, etc)

Much thanks!

Comment: Why do all results have to be displayed at the same time? If you're able to paginate, that would solve a lot of problems for you.

Comment: I was concerned that building paginate, filter, multi-column sort and search features was going to be a tall order via the standard WP ajax compared to letting jQuery dataTables do the heavy lifting.<br/>Plus the download to csv was a semi-critical feature that I figured all the data had to come down anyways might as well start there.
<br/>
<br/>
It does have an (AJAX mode for server side processing)[http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html] that might be a good place to start. But still not sure how to get the download to .csv work when using pagination.

Answer (score 0):

if data doesn't get updated constantly, maybe try static html files, here's a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/really-static/) for you. but as suggested by CodeMoose, pagination is your friend also.